# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value [swift 3.0]

Tags: ios, swift

I’m building an app with Swift 3.0.
So I have this code:

```
if let cofig = ConfigCoreDataController.shared.loadConfig() {
   self.textNumber.text = cofig.numero_centrale
}
```

If I try to start my application, I have this error:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

the loadConfig method is like this:

```
func loadConfig() -> Config! {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Config> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Config")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    let urls = self.loadConfigFromFetchRequest(request: request)
    if urls.count > 0
    {
        return urls[0]
    }else{
        return nil
    }

}
```

now, where is the problem ?

Comment: Your problem is you returning Config as nil when `urls.count == 0`. But you force unwrapping the return value `func loadConfig() -> Config!`. It should be `func loadConfig() -> Config?`

Comment: should be : func loadConfig() -> Config?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if 'urls' is Optional with nil value.

```
func loadConfig() -> Config? {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Config> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Config")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    if let urls = self.loadConfigFromFetchRequest(request: request)
    {
        if urls.count > 0
        {
            return urls[0]
        }else{
            return nil
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: sorry @Adolfo but my app was in error in this poit:  self.textNumber.text = cofig.numero_centrale

Comment: Check if numero_centrale is nil